# process input image & make duplicate image,& store in another directory

Tags: python

i want it to read input image from a directory & make duplicate image and store in another output directory.Now problem is input image,output image and script is in same path.I want input image directory and output image directory

This is what I have so far

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil


import re

#reads csv

df = pd.read_csv('rosary.csv')
df['Image'] = df.ImageName + "_" + df.ImageWChain + ".jpg"

#checking if column "ImageWChain" has "jpg" extension,then concat .jpg
if ".jpg" not in df.ImageWChain:
    df['ImageWChain'] = df.ImageWChain + ".jpg"

if ".jpg" not in df.ImageName:
    df['ImageName'] = df.ImageName + ".jpg"


#writes to new csv
df.to_csv('new.csv',index=False)
old_image = df.ImageName
new_image = df.Image



#creates duplicate images with renamed imagename

input_path='D:/New/Input_ImageFolder'
output_path='D:/New/Output_ImageFolder'

input_file=os.path.join(input_path,old_image)
output_file=os.path.join(output_path,new_image)



for old_image, new_image in zip(df.ImageName, df.Image):
    shutil.copy2(input_file, output_file)
```

Comment: Could you please add a sample input and output, and show the exact issue?

Comment: Now problem is input image,output image and script is in same path.I want input image directory and output image directory. But it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying by shutil.copy2, you have to indicate the input and output file path.

For example you have the paths defined as:

```
input_path='D:\\New\\Input_ImageFolder\\'
output_path='D:\\New\\Output_ImageFolder\\'
```

Next, you have to issue the following codes BEFORE you run the copy command:

```
input_file=os.path.join(input_path,old_image)
output_file=os.path.join(output_path,new_image)
```

Then, you can perform the copy operation as you mentioned:

```
shutil.copy2(input_file, output_file)
```

Comment: thanks @Simon MC. Cheng still not working as expected .... https://postimg.org/image/jtgqo38ix/

Comment: 1. have you import the os package by [import os] in the beginning of the code?
2. Please place the input_file and output_file lines inside your for loop to try again